# Explain these two regular expressions (octal notation and hexadecimal notation)

Tags: php, regex, hex, octal

I know this is a stupid question but I want to know what the meaning means in simple terms for each sequence below.

```
\[0-7]{1,3}
```

the sequence of characters matching the regular expression is a character in octal notation

```
\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}
```

the sequence of characters matching the regular expression is a character in hexadecimal notation

Comment: Do you know what regular expressions are? Also, neither regex is correct.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know now? What the expressions are doing? Or what the sentences mean?

Comment: @rudi @Rafe Why all the condescension?  He wants to know what the sentences mean, which is a fair question. The examples come straight from the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: I'm not a regex guru, but the first example is plain wrong, though, isn't it? Seeing as not every number starting with 0-7 is necessarily an octal number? Am I not seeing something?

Comment: @Pekka: As far as I can see this shouldn't be regex, just "a kind of". It just takes the character-group- (`[]`) and quantifier- (`{a,b}`) -notation, thats all.

Comment: @Pekka notice the leading \. Inside double-quoted strings `$a = "\123";` would be the char with ascii code 123 in octal, or 83 in decimal.

Comment: @Carlos ah, fair enough! It is a regex to catch `\xxx` notation - that explains it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that if you have a string like `"foo bar \041"`, `\041` will be treated as octal representation of a character. Similar for the hexadecimal sequence.

The regular expressions define the structure the character sequences have to follow in order to be interpreted as octal or hex representation:

- For octal: a slash `\` followed by one to three digits between `0` and `7`.
- For hex: a slash `\` followed by `x` followed by one or two characters which can be either digits or upper or lower case letters.

**Have a look at the [*ASCII table*](http://www.asciitable.com/) to see each character's octal and hexadecimal equivalent.**

For example:

```
echo "\064\062"; // echos 42
```

In hex:

```
echo "\x52\x50";
```

Answer (score 2):

Those two regular expressions define the way the number should be formatted. The `[0-7]` means to allow all digits between zero and seven, and the `{1,3}` after it means that that there may be between one and three of those digits.

Similarly in the second regular expression, `[0-9A-Fa-f]` means all the numbers between zero and nine, all the uppercase letters between A and F, and all the lowercase letters between a and f. The `{1,2}` means that there must be one or two of those digits/letters.

Comment: You are forgetting about the leading \ or \x

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem with your regex, it won't test a string properly because you don't have ^ in the beginning and $ in the end, but never mind that.

ok, the first one is

```
match range 0-7 one 1 to 3 charcters
```

second one is

```
match range 0-9 AND A-F (capital) AND a-f(small) 1 to 2 charcters
```

The x in the second one is probably a mistake...

Comment: You might want to read the other answers and the comment below the question.

Comment: ah... I didn't think much about the \... so there should be an X in the other one as well?